# How does the accept() function work?

Tags: c, sockets, server

I have a question about the `accept()` function in C.

When a server receive a connection, the `accept()` function creates a new socket to communicate with the client, and then let the "old socket" listening for new connections.

Then, I understand that the server can communicate with the client through the "new socket", but how can the client communicate with the "new socket" (because the client don't know about this "new socket") ?

Comment: The client created the "new socket" before the server knew about it with `socket()` and pointed it at the server with `connect()`.  Note: the binary "socket ID" represents different memory locations in different processes likely on different physical machines.

Comment: The client doesn't know about the *old* socket either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the server side, the listening socket is associated with only a local IP and port and is in the LISTEN state.

In contrast, accepted sockets on the server (as well as connected sockets on the client) are identified by a local IP and port as well as a remote IP and port and is in the ESTABLISHED state.

On the client side, it doesn't matter that the server uses a listening socket separate from the connected socket.  By the time the client returns from `connect`, the server has returned from `accept` and the socket descriptors returned from each can communicate with each other.

Comment: So is it possible that multiple sockets in the server run in the same local port? Are they distinguished by remote address and port?

Comment: @Milack That is correct.  A listening socket can call `accept` multiple times to accept multiple connections.  All of those accepted sockets will have the same local IP and port, but the remote IP and/or port will differ.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But then, after the connect() (on a socket "sock") return, if the client write something on the same socket ("sock"), how is done the "link" between the client's accepted socket and the "new socket" created with accept() ? I mean, how can the client automatically write on the socket created with the accept()?

Comment: @Masiwan The client's connected socket is associated with a remote IP and port (i.e. the one it connected to) as well as a local IP and port.  So when the client does a `send`, it sends to the associated remote IP:port.  The same is true on the server side of the accepted socket.

Comment: @dbush So, if I understand, before the connect() call the client's socket is not associated with a remote IP/port, but then after the connect() return (and then the accept() return), the client's socket is associated ?

Comment: I learnt that the backend application has to make an accept() sys call on the socket that is listening to new requests which then returns a new file descriptor(which is a socket representing the connection b/w the client and the server). But, isn't the listening socket already bound to a specific backend application? Isn't the socket bound to the application which actually created it in the first place? Or is it that multiple applications can be bound to that single listening socket and therefore they can get a file descriptor for their own use?

Comment: @asn An application can have multiple open sockets.  For example, a server app will have one listening socket and zero or more connected sockets returned by `accept`, one for each client it's connected to.  Or a client app can decide to connect to multiple distinct servers, with an open socket for each one.  You could even have an app that both listens for connections as a server and makes connections as a client.

Answer (score 4):

Any communication in IP protocol (including TCP/IP) occurs between two endpoints. The endpoints are always host:port. In the TCP world, the two endpoints identify the connection. A socket is associated with a connection, not with an endpoint.

Thus, you can have 2 sockets returned from 2 accept() calls, describing 2 distinct connections.

Here is an example of `netstat -an` output on a unix machine:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 170.44.26.7:22              161.231.133.178:11550       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 170.44.26.7:22              161.231.133.178:33938       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 170.44.26.7:22              161.231.133.178:13875       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 170.44.26.7:22              161.231.133.178:34968       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 170.44.26.7:22              161.231.133.178:44212       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 170.44.26.7:22              161.231.133.178:34967       ESTABLISHED
```

Here we have a listening socket, and a few connections (each backed by its own socket) resulting from `accept()` on that socket.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are an abstraction of the network programming API. On the wire and for the client there is still only a single connection and the client does not see if the server is using a network API with listen, accept etc or if the server is using some other API or raw sockets to establish the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that a TCP (an end point in a TCP/IP transmission) is uniquely identified by the couple IPaddress/port_number. When a client asks for a connection, it does it using its IP and port number, a pair which is unique. That operation binds SRCIP+SRCPORT to DSTIP+DSTPORT, and those 4 numbers (the two IPs plus the two ports) uniquely identify a connection. So the two sockets on the server really refer to two different connections/streams.